# How to get Mobile sim number(GSM) in android

Tags: android, mobile, telephonymanager

I am developing an Android application. In that i need to get the user mobile sim number for calling purposes automatically. But i am facing the problem in getting the mobile number of the user. 
 I have tried this.

```
          TelephonyManager telemamanger = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String getSimSerialNumber = telemamanger.getSimSerialNumber();

    String deviceID = telemamanger.getDeviceId();
    String getSimNumber = telemamanger.getLine1Number();
```

and this

```
          TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    String network;
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if(cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().getTypeName().equals("MOBILE"))
        network = "cellnetwork/4G";
    else if(cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().getTypeName().equals("WIFI"))
        network = "wifi";
    else
        network ="na";

   String uphone = tm.getLine1Number();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),uphone+" "+network,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

In these, i am getting all the information i want except the mobile number. 
Is there any alternate method to get mobile number like in BHIM app. 
In BHIM app they are getting the mobile numbers automatically(whether it is single or dual sim).

Answer (score 0):

Sure!

These are some informations that you can get both on SubscriptionManager and SubscriptionInfo.

Though I'm not really sure on what permissions you need to do that on a 3rd party app. This is how I do on my company's framework:

```
private void fillSimNumber(TelephonyManager tm, SubscriptionInfo subscriptionInfo) {
    final String rawNumber =  tm.getLine1Number(subscriptionInfo.getSubscriptionId());

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(rawNumber)) {
        mSimNumber.setText(rawNumber);
    }
}
```

Best of Luck!

Comment: I am getting this error. Error:(79, 37) error: method getLine1Number in class TelephonyManager cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found: int
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: Please, consider ALWAYS reading the documentation before using any method. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getLine1Number()

Comment: getLine1Number() with given type is a hiden API on android framework. So you will not be able to use it other than being a system app.